# не получается сделать редирект

Tags: angular5

есть код:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.less']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private r: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        switch(e.keyCode){
          //f4
          case 115:{
            // как тут сделать редирект??
            break; 
          }
          default:
          {
            console.log("вы нажали " + e.keyCode);
            break;
          }
        }
    };
  }

  private onKeyEnter(){
    //this.r.navigate();
  }
}
```

в общем вопрос в коде. либо на том месте нужно сделать функцию `onKeyEnter`. Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: какой редирект?

Comment: @overthesanity на мой же домен...по сути надо заюзать переменную `r`, вот только я не знаю как

Comment: как заюзать? какой редирект на домен?)

Comment: [вы читали это?](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component)

Comment: @overthesanity именно в case не видно `this.r`

Comment: `document.onkeydown = (e) => ...`

Comment: @overthesanity это из-за того, что если я пишу через `function` то `this` привязывается к самой функции?

Comment: нет, к `document`